# Python: list index out of range halfway through list iteration

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

First off, list index being out of range does sound simple and self-explanatory... but looking around I can find no explanation for my situation; I am iterating through a list 19 items long and at the 9th item my console throws the "list index out of range" error". I am at a loss for explanations quite frankly...

*I am using phantomjs and selenium to scrape a webpage... THANKS IN ADVANCE!

```
# data list
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
        xpath = [
        businessName,firstName,lastName,ubi,info,
        licenseType,licenseNumber,licenseEffectiveDate,licenseExpirationDate,status,
        bondProvider,bondNumber,bondAmount,bondEffectiveDate,bondEffectiveDate,insuranceProvider,
        insuranceNumber,insuranceAmount,insuranceEffectiveDate,insuranceExpirationDate
        ] 

        data = [
        "businessName","firstName","lastName","ubi","info",
        "licenseType","licenseNumber","licenseEffectiveDate","licenseExpirationDate","status",
        "bondProvider","bondNumber","bondAmount","bondEffectiveDate","bondEffectiveDate","insuranceProvider",
        "insuranceNumber","insuranceAmount","insuranceEffectiveDate","insuranceExpirationDate"
        ] 
#
#
# xpath check and grab function
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        i = 0
        while i <= len(data):
           result = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath[i]).text    #checks is xpath exists
           print i
           print data[i] + " = " + str(result) 
           i += 1
```

Comment: What is `i <= data[i]` supposed to do?

Comment: Your while loop will definitely go out of bounds, are you sure the error occurs on the 9th iteration? Try changing while (i <= data[i]) to while i <= len(data):

Comment: you're much better to use `for i in range(len(xpath)-1` rather than a while loop.

Comment: I'm also mystified by `i <= data[i]`. Guess it's a good thing that this becomes a `TypeError` in python 3.

Comment: @JacobH I have update to what you suggested about and am still getting an erron on the 9th iteration

Comment: when I delete "result = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath[i]).text" I get past the 9th iteration no problem...

Answer (score 3):

If, as it appears from your example, the items in `xpath` and `data` will always correspond directly to each other, you could do this more easily and cleanly by using the loop expression:

```
for elem_xpath, name in zip(xpath, data):
```

If you *need* the index `i` as well, use `enumerate`:

```
for i, (elem_xpath, name) in enumerate(zip(xpath, data)):
```

Comment: This is very helpful and I will use it... but I have just discovered that commenting out the following line gets me past the 9th iteration: "result = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath[i]).text"